# Pass data from UIViewController to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

I need to pass the data from the UIViewController to AppDelegate. But should not with NSUserDefaults. I could not find an alternative for it even i don't want it.

Comment: NSUserDefaults is used to store data. Why do you want to pass data using this mechanism? May be you should specifically describe the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need access to your delegate, I always create my singleton access in the next way :

```
// your imports...

#define appDelegate ((YourAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)

@class YourAppDelegate

//...
```

in the .h file of YourAppDelegate.

It´s helpful and useful, but do not abuse of the delegate to access to particular things, try to use a different way. Anyway, you can access in that way.